# primefaces commandbutton fires actionlistener inside html table when clicking anywhere inside the table

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

I have an HTML table with several primefaces commandbuttons each with their own actionListener="#{  }" and anytime I click inside the table, anywhere, the first rendered commandbutton's actionListener fires. Why is this happening/how can I fix it?

```
<p:panelGrid columns="4" layout="grid">
    <p:outputPanel>
        <p:outputLabel id="technicalApprovalLabel" title="" styleClass="borderIcons">
            <i class="#{ cc.attrs.object.techApprover == 0 ? 'Blue' : cc.attrs.object.techApprover > 0 ? 'Green' : 'BoldGray' } Fs60 fa fa-gears"></i>
        </p:outputLabel>
        <p:tooltip id="toolTipTechnicalApprovalApproved" for="technicalApprovalLabel" value="Technical Approver - #{ cc.attrs.object.techName }" rendered="#{ cc.attrs.object.techApprover > 0 }"/>
        <p:tooltip id="toolTipTechnicalApprovalRequired" for="technicalApprovalLabel" value="Technical Approval" rendered="#{ cc.attrs.object.techApprover == 0 }"/>
        <p:tooltip id="toolTipTechnicalApprovalNotRequired" for="technicalApprovalLabel" value="Technical Approval Not Required" rendered="#{ cc.attrs.object.techApprover == -1 }"/>
    </p:outputPanel>

    <p:outputPanel>
        <p:outputLabel id="salesApprovalLabel" title="" styleClass="borderIcons">
            <i class="#{ cc.attrs.object.salesApprover == 0 ? 'Blue' : cc.attrs.object.salesApprover > 0 ? 'Green' : 'BoldGray' } Fs60 fa fa-tags"></i>
        </p:outputLabel>
        <p:tooltip id="toolTipSalesApprovalApproved" for="salesApprovalLabel" value="Sales Approver - #{ cc.attrs.object.salesName }" rendered="#{ cc.attrs.object.salesApprover > 0 }"/>
        <p:tooltip id="toolTipSalesApprovalRequired" for="salesApprovalLabel" value="Sales Approval" rendered="#{ cc.attrs.object.salesApprover == 0 }"/>
        <p:tooltip id="toolTipSalesApprovalNotRequired" for="salesApprovalLabel" value="Sales Approval Not Required" rendered="#{ cc.attrs.object.salesApprover == -1 }"/>
    </p:outputPanel>

    <p:outputPanel>
        <p:outputLabel id="financeApprovalLabel" title="" styleClass="borderIcons">
            <i class="#{ cc.attrs.object.financialApprover == 0 ? 'Blue' : cc.attrs.object.financialApprover > 0 ? 'Green' : 'BoldGray' } Fs60 icon-chart"></i>
        </p:outputLabel>
        <p:tooltip id="toolTipFinanceApprovalApproved" for="financeApprovalLabel" value="Finance Approver - #{ cc.attrs.object.financeName }" rendered="#{ cc.attrs.object.financialApprover > 0 }"/>
        <p:tooltip id="toolTipFinanceApprovalRequired" for="financeApprovalLabel" value="Finance Approval" rendered="#{ cc.attrs.object.financialApprover == 0 }"/>
        <p:tooltip id="toolTipFinanceApprovalNotRequired" for="financeApprovalLabel" value="Finance Approval Not Required" rendered="#{ cc.attrs.object.financialApprover == -1 }"/>
    </p:outputPanel>

    <p:outputPanel>
        <p:outputLabel id="executiveApprovalLabel" title="" styleClass="borderIcons">
            <i class="#{ cc.attrs.object.execApprover == 0 ? 'Blue' : cc.attrs.object.execApprover > 0 ? 'Green' : 'BoldGray' } Fs60 fa fa-university"></i>
        </p:outputLabel>
        <p:tooltip id="toolTipExecutiveApprovalApproved" for="executiveApprovalLabel" value="Executive Approver - #{ cc.attrs.object.execName }" rendered="#{ cc.attrs.object.execApprover > 0 }"/>
        <p:tooltip id="toolTipExecutiveApprovalRequired" for="executiveApprovalLabel" value="Executive Approval" rendered="#{ cc.attrs.object.execApprover == 0 }"/>
        <p:tooltip id="toolTipExecutiveApprovalNotRequired" for="executiveApprovalLabel" value="Executive Approval Not Required" rendered="#{ cc.attrs.object.execApprover == -1 }"/>
    </p:outputPanel>

    <!-- 2nd row -->

    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{ cc.attrs.object.techApprover == 0 }">
        <p:commandButton styleClass="GreenBack" icon="fa fa-check Fs16 White" actionListener="#{ cc.attrs.object.techApprove() }" id="TechnicalApprovalmessage" update="TechnicalApprovalGrowl" />
        <p:commandButton styleClass="RedBack" icon="fa fa-close Fs16 White" onclick="PF('techRejectionDialog').show();"/>
        <p:growl id="TechnicalApprovalGrowl" for="TechnicalApprovalmessage" life="6000" />
    </p:outputPanel>

    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{ cc.attrs.object.salesApprover == 0 }">
        <p:commandButton styleClass="GreenBack" icon="fa fa-check Fs16 White" actionListener="#{ cc.attrs.object.salesApprove() }" id="SalesApprovalmessage" update="SalesApprovalGrowl" />
        <p:commandButton styleClass="RedBack" icon="fa fa-close Fs16 White" onclick="PF('salesRejectionDialog').show();"/>
        <p:growl id="SalesApprovalGrowl" for="SalesApprovalmessage" life="6000" />
    </p:outputPanel>

    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{ cc.attrs.object.financialApprover == 0 }" >
        <p:commandButton styleClass="GreenBack" icon="fa fa-check Fs16 White" actionListener="#{ cc.attrs.object.financeApprove() }" id="FinancialApprovalmessage" update="FinancialApprovalGrowl" />
        <p:commandButton styleClass="RedBack" icon="fa fa-close Fs16 White" onclick="PF('financeRejectionDialog').show();"/>
        <p:growl id="FinancialApprovalGrowl" for="FinancialApprovalmessage" life="6000" />
    </p:outputPanel>

    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{ cc.attrs.object.execApprover == 0 }" >
        <p:commandButton styleClass="GreenBack" icon="fa fa-check Fs16 White" actionListener="#{ cc.attrs.object.execApprove() }" id="ExecutiveApprovalmessage" update="ExecutiveApprovalGrowl" />
        <p:commandButton styleClass="RedBack" icon="fa fa-close Fs16 White" onclick="PF('execRejectionDialog').show();"/>
        <p:growl id="ExecutiveApprovalGrowl" for="ExecutiveApprovalmessage" life="6000" />
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Can you share with us the code

Comment: Explain please how it isn't mcve. Why are you always more interested in finding faults in my question/code than you are in trying to help solve the problem? @Kukeltje

Comment: @piercen shouldnt the p:row tags be used with p:datatable or p:panelgrid instead of html table tags? can you try replacing html tags and use p:panelGrid??

Comment: I have tried changing the html tags to all primeface tags, like p:panelgrid with columns and p:outputPanels and still received the same results @EvaMariam

Comment: Unfortunately I do not @EvaMariam

Comment: Can you define new code for me please? @EvaMariam

Comment: Updated code @EvaMariam

Comment: I'm not sure why it happens, after trying to figure it out for awhile now. If I click anywhere, such as    <i class="#{ cc.attrs.object.techApprover == 0 ? 'Blue' : cc.attrs.object.techApprover > 0 ? 'Green' : 'BoldGray' } Fs60 fa fa-gears"></i> (the first icon, not associated with a button directly) the first rendered p:commandbutton fires

Comment: Changing it to anything, such as outputText, doesn't change it. It seems to happen when clicking in any openspace that's left over. The text/icons do not fill the entire table cell/div so by clicking the extra space inbetween, above, or below fires the commandbutton @EvaMariam

Comment: Well it does not for me, not with PrimeFaces 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, not in FF, Chrome or IE. I added an empty h:head and around your code an h:body and h:form. Same as you?